# Digital Ocean Ubuntu Run ServiceStack as a Daemon

Tags: ubuntu, mono-framework

All,

I have successfully installed my ServiceStack console app on my DigitalOcean Ubuntu MEAN Stack droplet and can run it from the command line using mono. When I do this, my app is accessible using Postman from my laptop.

I have also tried to use Upstart to run my app as a daemon. I can see from the logging that it successfully launches when I reboot, but unless I am logged in as root and have started my console app from the command line, I can't access the console app from the outside when running as the daemon. I have tried this with ufw enabled (configured to allow the port I am using) and disabled and it makes no difference. I can see in both syslog and GeoAPIConsole.log the the console app fired and started on port 1337, but I still can't access it from the outside.

I am reasonably certain this is a permissions issue in my upstart config file for my console app, but since I am brand new to linux, I am unclear as to my next step to get this console app available as a daemon.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated...

Bruce

```
# ServiceStack GeoAPIConsole Application

# description “GeoAPIConsole”
# author      “Bruce Parr”

setuid root
# start on started rc
start on started networking
stop on stopping rc

respawn

exec start-stop-daemon --start --exec /usr/bin/mono /var/console/GeoAPIConsole.exe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked. I added a user geoapiconsole and added the -S and -c switches

```
# ServiceStack Example Application

description "ServiceStack Example"
author      "ServiceStack"

start on started rc
stop on stopping rc

respawn

exec start-stop-daemon -S -c geoapiconsole --exec /usr/bin/mono /var/console/GeoAPIConsole.exe
```